# ElasticSearch expectable performances

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, database-performance

I am working on porting a search engine from an sql database to elasticsearch.
The main reason for doing it is to be able to compute facets easily.

Currently we have facets on the sql by generating precalc tables. It works well but it's a pain to maintain and facets are supported only on a subset of the datas.

Now the ES prototype is working, I am benchmarking the two solutions, and it appears that the ES version is a little under the sql version in terms of performance (in terms of maintainability it's far better).

I've used the exact same machine configurations, a 64 bits platform, 32 gigs of ram, an ssd disk, and a quad core Intel Xeon at 3ghz to compare the sql and ES.

The document is not small, there's around 200 fields, depending on the request, script based sorting is used, and facets are always computed on 8 fields of the doc.

The index contains 3 millions of docs, if I'm not mistaken it's relatively small to what ES can handle.

In terms of query, I use a filtered query, and for some requests, a custom_filters_score query to compute the score and use it for sorting.

Some of the filters are global because of the facets but there's always some filters in the filtered query, so the number of docs scanned should be reduced (not all the index is scanned).

I use two measures in my tests : the time spent on the server to execute the search, and the number of queries by second executed by the client running 100 threads in parallel.

For elasticsearch, the average time spent on the server is around 500 ms for each query (for 100 queries in parallel), and the average queries by second on the client is around 160 (some ms are lost in building the query, sending it, receiving results, and parsing them).
And this is with an index having 1 shard and 0 replicas, when I increase the number of shards/replicas, performances drop significantly.

For sql, the average time spent to execute a query is around 360 ms (idem, with 100 queries running in parallel), and the average queries by second on the client is around 200.

I know it's hard to compare, but as I don't have any idea of the results I can expect, I wonder if someone can comment on these measures.

Maybe I missed something and it should be an order of magnitude faster, or maybe these are the typical results for similar environnements to mine, I don't know.

What can I expect in my case?
What did you observe under similar circumstances with ES?
Does it support concurrent requests well?
Should the time to execute a query be in the range of 500 ms when making 100 queries at the same time?
Are there some ways to improve search performances?

Any information or comments are welcome, this is an important part for the decision to industrialize the prototype or not.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Nobody wants to comment on this ?

Comment: You might want to try making it a bit less ranty...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a question; this sounds more like a discussion.

That said, not many can comment because all our use-case are different. You are purely using this as a facet analytical tool. I use ElasticSearch as both a database and a real time analytical tool. So my benchmark of what works for me will be dramatically different from you.

Version wise, I am still using 1.8.7 (because of Logstash) but the current version is at 0.19.4 at this time of writing. There are just too many different parameters to even talk about a standard benchmark as Elastic Search is not exactly a standard industrial tool that people use today, so I guess you do need to rephrase what you ask in order for people to actually comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you an exact answer but your numbers don't sound too unexpected.

- Make sure you have optimised your index with number of segments = 1.
- Turn up the thread pool size in elastic search.
- Make sure the Xms and Xmx are the same, use mock lock all.

These should give you some boost in performance though I'm not surprised that a performant relational DB with only 3 million documents is performing as well or better, the difference is that the DB will get slower whereas ES will perform the same with 100's of millions.